# Laravel Sanctum Unauthenticated after login

Tags: laravel, authentication, axios, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to setup auth for SPA (react) with sanctum.

Whenever I login successfully, and then, try to get a route that is in auth:sanctum middleware, it return me 401 Unauthenticated.

These are my urls :

SPA : localhost:3000

Backend : https://local-erp.XXX.com/

These are my config files :

sanctum.php :

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,https://local-erp.XXX.com',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

kernel.php:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

.env :

```
SESSION_DOMAIN:.localhost
```

I also tried `*.localhost`, `localhost`

This is my LoginController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Service\Ldap;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'sAMAccountName' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my queries :

```
axios.get("https://local-erp.XXX.com/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(response => {
      axios.post("https://local-erp.XXX.com/login",  {username: "xxx", password: "xxxx"})
    })
```

which returns both 204 OK Status Code.

Then when I send this :

```
const querytest = () => {
    axios.get('https://local-erp.XXX.com/api/users/5/holiday-balance')
  }
```

It returns `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`

I know there is a lot of post about this, but I tried everything I could find and nothing fixed my problem.

It might be good to know, I'm actually moving a laravel blade app into a separate spa and back application. Currently, auth worked with ldap (which must still work).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure the csrf and token is included in the headers?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to see that, when opening request header i got : 
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin:
http://localhost:3000
Referer:
http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
X-Requested-With:
XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I found a information that might be important, it seems that the error is coming from a difference between names of both domains.
`this attempt to set a cookie was blocked because its domain attribute` is the error I got from headers response.
I still couldn't find how to avoid it since my laravel config seems correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After severals test, I found it was not possible to use different domains names.

In my case I couldn't use the same one, even if I used subdomains, so my solution was to auth with API token.
It works like a charm and is used as an RESTFUL API.